# How do I get the "session data" shown in an error?

Tags: eclipse

I am adding some functionality to an existing application to show debug info. When examining an error from the error log view it shows something called "session data", typically it looks like:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20090917-0800
java.version=1.6.0_11
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=sv_SE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
```

This is something that could be useful to know. how can I get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of those information should be able from a Plugin through the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` class, as shown by the [`org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.SystemVariableResolver` source code](http://www.enerjy.com/explorer/projects/eclipse/org/eclipse/debug/internal/core/SystemVariableResolver.java.html):

```
public String resolveValue(IDynamicVariable variable, String argument) throws CoreException {
    if ("ARCH".equals(argument)) { //$NON-NLS-1$ 
        return Platform.getOSArch(); 
    } else if ("ECLIPSE_HOME".equals(argument)) { //$NON-NLS-1$ 
        URL installURL = Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL(); 
        IPath ppath = new Path(installURL.getFile()).removeTrailingSeparator(); 
        return getCorrectPath(ppath.toOSString()); 
    } else if ("NL".equals(argument)) { //$NON-NLS-1$ 
        return Platform.getNL(); 
    } else if ("OS".equals(argument)) { //$NON-NLS-1$ 
        return Platform.getOS(); 
    } else if ("WS".equals(argument)) { //$NON-NLS-1$ 
        return Platform.getWS(); 
    } 
    return null;
}
```

`Platform.getCommandLineArgs()` should complete the display for the eclipse session (not for your program though).

---

For a RCP program, see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg35628.html)

> Using the `Application start(IApplicationContext context)` method:

```
String[] args = (String[]) context.getArguments().get(IApplicationContext.APPLICATION_ARGS);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it. For some reason I thought there was something fancier than Platform.get* methods for this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing there is the session info for the Eclipse program, not yours.

Your program is run in a JVM of its own, and with far fewer arguments. The eclipse environment stuff is not really very relevant for your program.

The actual command line arguments to your program are of course available as arguments to the `main()` method. A few other items of potential interest will be visible in the Java properties, which you can obtain with System.getProperty(). This documentation contains the names of the "standard" properties: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29